# RevenueCat: How to get the purchaseToken in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, revenuecat

I need the purchaseToken for our server. This field exsits in the Android API,

```
/**
  * Token that uniquely identifies a purchase.
  */
 val purchaseToken: String,
```

And it is received upon purchase. But iOS API of the purchase function below doesn't send it back

```
func purchase(package: Package) async throws -> PurchaseResultData
```

When I debug, I see a similar data inside this:

```
purchaseResultData.customerInfo.allPurchases.first?.value["id"]
```

But `allPurchases` is private so I can't get it this way.

Any ideas?

Comment: `purchaseToken` is an Android object, it doesn't exist on iOS... What is it that you're trying to save? https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase#getPurchaseToken()

Answer (score 1):

I notice that `PurchaseResultData` is a `typealias` for

```
typealias PurchaseResultData = (transaction: StoreTransaction?,
                                customerInfo: CustomerInfo,
                                userCancelled: Bool)
```

Instead of checking the `customerInfo` for the `purchaseToken`, maybe the `transaction` object has this information as I can see that the type [StoreTransaction](https://revenuecat-docs.netlify.app/documentation/revenuecat/storetransaction) has a property called `productIdentifier`

So maybe try

```
purchaseResultData.transaction.productIdentifier
```

**Update with some other ideas**

- Maybe try looking at the [transaction identifier](https://revenuecat-docs.netlify.app/documentation/revenuecat/storetransaction#:%7E:text=var%20transactionIdentifier%3A%20String)
- Maybe exploring the store kit objects, namely `SK1Transaction` and `SK2Transaction` which are properties of `StoreTransaction`
- I have not used this specific API, but it seems like [allPurchasedProductIdentifiers](https://revenuecat-docs.netlify.app/documentation/revenuecat/customerinfo/allpurchasedproductidentifiers) is a public property within [CustomerInfo](https://revenuecat-docs.netlify.app/documentation/revenuecat/customerinfo) so I wonder if this is different from the `allPurchases` you tried

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, it is not it. Is it a longer numberOnly var. The one I am looking for is shorter and has chars as well.

Comment: @Luda - I see. I just updated with some new ideas. Have a look if maybe they help ?

Comment: I will check your suggestions soon. I am giving you an upvote anyway for your kindness and politness.

Comment: I was hoping it would be customerInfo.allPurchasedProductIdentifiers, unfortunately it is the ids of products configured in AppStore

Comment: @Luda Hmm ... Other ideas I can think of. 1. I found some support email on an article by them, you can check if they have some answer: `support@revenuecat.com`. 2. Can you share the Android code that worked, maybe it has some hints for us ? 3. I will leave some links related to product identifier I found on revenue cat forums, maybe they will help

Comment: https://community.revenuecat.com/general-questions-7/error-with-product-identifiers-ios-724

Comment: https://community.revenuecat.com/sdks-51/invalid-product-identifiers-still-after-trying-all-points-in-reference-post-1308

Comment: https://community.revenuecat.com/general-questions-7/invalid-product-identifiers-992

Comment: https://community.revenuecat.com/search?q=product%20identifier%20ios

Comment: This is mine. Waiting for an answer https://community.revenuecat.com/sdks-51/how-to-get-the-purchasetoken-in-ios-1451